Sketch where one caveman has invented the complete English language
I'm looking for the Not the Nine O'Clock News episode where cavemen have not yet invented human speech and suddenly one caveman has invented the complete English language "forming words into sentences". Can we find the specific episode to look for?

I think this might be quite difficult, full episodes of the show have never been released and I don't remember that scene from the two best of DVDs.

check here: http://www.tv.com/shows/not-the-nine-oclock-news/episodes/

Lots of sketch info in this page too. FWIW, one of them (in series 2, episode 5) is called "Neanderthal man speaks French".

This is from Episode 11 (S02E05), and Walt correctly identified that it's the "Neanderthal man speaks French" scene, but it's not a great description because that only describes the punchline of the scene, and they certainly look more like cavemen.
I'm really struggling to find another source to back it up but it does exist out there copied from some old Betamax tapes, so here's some screenshots and a transcript of the scene:


[Caveman 1 (Mel Smith) and Caveman 2 (Rowan Atkinson) are sitting by a campfire and grunting]



[Caveman 3 (Griff Rhys Jones) approaches from the distance]


Caveman 3: Hello! [Laughing] Hello! Sorry to disturb you! Hello there! Hello! Ha! 
Caveman 3: I have this marvellous new invention, you see, a fantastic new invention: a language!

[Cavemen 1 & 2 grunting, look at each other]


Caveman 3: You see, instead of using noises like 'ugh ugh', you use lots of different noises and you give them associated meanings and you, and you- make words. [Laughs] course you probably wouldn't understand it yet.

Caveman 3: But, you see, these words can, you can really express quite complicated ideas with the right grammar and syntax and th-

[Caveman 2 hits Caveman 3 with a club]


Caveman 2: Je ne tué parce que je déteste les Anglais (I killed him because I hate the English)


